# Why did my array get transposed?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, pass-by-pointer

I want declare a 2D array of doubles (`double** data`). I want to pass this by address to a helper function; so I pass `&data` and the helper function has argument `double*** d`.

Passed this way, the indexing that I used for the 2D array in the main function is no longer working.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void helperfunction(double*** data, int n, int c) {

    printf("\nIn helper function\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("(%i %i %lf) ", i, j, *data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 4; //number of rows
    int c = 4; //number of columns

    double count = 0.0;

    double** data = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double* row = malloc(c * sizeof(double));
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            row[j] = count;
            count += 1.2;
        }
        data[i] = row;
    }

    printf("In main function\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("(%i %i %lf) ", i, j, data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    helperfunction(&data, n, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In main function
(0 0 0.000000) (0 1 1.200000) (0 2 2.400000) (0 3 3.600000) 
(1 0 4.800000) (1 1 6.000000) (1 2 7.200000) (1 3 8.400000) 
(2 0 9.600000) (2 1 10.800000) (2 2 12.000000) (2 3 13.200000) 
(3 0 14.400000) (3 1 15.600000) (3 2 16.800000) (3 3 18.000000) 

In helper function
(0 0 0.000000) (0 1 4.800000) (0 2 9.600000) (0 3 14.400000) 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Obviously, something is wrong with the indexing when I deference the address (`*data[i][j]`) in the helper function. What is causing this?

Comment: precedence.  [] has higher precedence than *.  Use `(*data)[i][j]`

Comment: Note: you're not creating a 2D array. Your creating a 1D array of pointers to 1D-arrays. Those are very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*data[i][j]` does not do what you think. It is equivalent to `*(data[i][j])`. Your options are:

1. Use `(*data)[i][j]` instead, or
2. Pass `data` (instead of `&data`) and use `data[i][j]` since passing a triple pointer isn't necessary here.

Comment: Thanks. This is a minimal example, so the triple pointer is necessary for the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just figured this out. The dereferencing using `[]` occurs before the deferencing using `*`. Therefore a call to `*data[i][j]` will cause the segmentation fault when i != 0, since the highest level pointer is only pointing to one thing, while the two lover levels of pointers point to arrays.

A solution is to use `data[0][i][j]` instead.

Comment: That's ugly, use parenthesizes, like Kevin suggests.

Comment: eh ... looks fine to me.

Comment: *ugly* is subjective. But to me `a[0]` has the meaning *access the first element of the array this points to* and `*a` has the meaning *dereference the pointer*. Even though they do the same thing the meaning is different.